# Msbuild command line argument at project-level not solution-level for changing AssemblyName

Tags: command-line, msbuild, clickonce

Is there any way to specify a command line argument for msbuild that will apply only to one project (i.e. project-level not solution-level), when building a multi-project solution?

The reason I ask is because I want to enable side-by-side installs of a click-once deployment. Let me give an example:

1) This works

> MSBuild "C:\Dev\MyProj\MyProj.Shell\MyProj.Shell.csproj"
>   /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /target:publish
>   /p:OutputPath="C:\Dev\Temp\" /p:ApplicationVersion=1.2.3.4
>   /p:ProductName="My Proj" /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Mixed
>   Platforms" /verbosity:diagnostic

2) This doesn't

> MSBuild "C:\Dev\MyProj\MyProj.Shell\MyProj.Shell.csproj"
>   /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /target:publish
>   /p:OutputPath="C:\Dev\Temp\" /p:ApplicationVersion=1.2.3.4
>   /p:ProductName="My Proj Test" /p:Configuration="Release"
>   /p:Platform="Mixed Platforms" /verbosity:diagnostic
>   /p:AssemblyName="MyProj.Test"

Just to clarify and re-iterate a couple of points:

- The only difference between 1 & 2 is the `/p:AssemblyName="MyProj.Text"`
- I'm using `/target:publish` so this is a click-once build
- This is a multi-project solution and it will build as such even though I'm just targeting a csproj file.

I know the reason why *Example 2* fails is because it renames every project's AssemblyName with the assembly name passed in, i.e. *MyProj.Test*. This makes some sense because parameters passed in through the command line are global, but then again I'm targeting just the csproj file.

Anyway that is what happens. So is there any way to pass in a msbuild command line parameter to change just the one AssemblyName property in the MyProj.Shell.csproj file?

Answer (score 17):

You can edit your project in question (its *.csproj* file) to obtain assembly name from a special property if it is specified, i.e.:

```
<AssemblyName Condition=" '$(ThisProjectNameOverrideAssemblyName)' == '' " >UsualAssemblyName</AssemblyName>
<AssemblyName Condition=" '$(ThisProjectNameOverrideAssemblyName)' != '' " >$(ThisProjectNameOverrideAssemblyName)</AssemblyName>
```

So when you build your project in question, you pass your `ThisProjectNameOverrideAssemblyName` to override `AssemblyName` for this project  only:

```
msbuild /p:ThisProjectNameOverrideAssemblyName=NewAssemblyName
```

Comment: Thank you Isantipov, this is a legitimate possibility, however, I'm looking for a generic way to do this for projects without modifying the csproj file. I suspect the answer to this is simply, "No you can't do it".

Comment: I was trying to figure this out for 2 days. Didn't understand why it wasn't working so thank you both for understanding the problem well enough to ask the question correctly and for the answer itself!

Comment: this just saved me.  I had a ton of work put into setting up a CI / CD process for a win forms application where I required side-by-side installs of the win forms.  The problem is the solution is a multi-project solution and the properties I was overriding were being applied to all dependent projects causing the build to fail.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447528/building-a-win-forms-application-with-dependent-projects-and-overriding-publish