# Building a Win Forms application with dependent projects and overriding publish properties with MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have inherited a WinForms application that is written in VB.NET. We are eventually going to move this to a web based application and the first thing I have done is introduce separate projects into the solution (in C#) that will become the components for the web services.

This application is has Azure Dev Ops build and publish pipelines set-up with 3 branches, 6 different environments.

I use MSBuild in the build definition - overriding the publish properties for each branch / environment:

```
/t:publish /p:InstallUrl=$(AppUpdateLocation) /p:UpdateUrl=$(AppUpdateLocation) /p:ApplicationVersion=$(REVISION_NUMBER) /p:ProductName=AOS-ProdSupport-Dev;AssemblyName=$(DEV_ASSEMBLY_NAME)
```

Basically I run MSBuild 2 X - once for a "Dev" environment and once for a "Test" environment.

When the artifact is published - I have two different builds for the respective environments.

Everything has been working great when it was just a vbproj project and a test project.

The problem I have just encountered is when I introduced several other projects to the solution.  My new solution looks like this:

[image]

When I build this in Visual Studio it works.  If attempt to build this solution with MSBuild (on Azure or locally) - it fails.  I get a missing assembly or reference for the AOS.Core project.

This project is a common library used by all.

```
##[error]AOS.Repository\CommissionAudit\CommissionAuditOrderByProvider.cs(2,11): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'AOS' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I believe I figured out what is causing the missing reference.  Looking at the actual build output - files generated - the AOS.Core\bin\Release directory doesn't contain a AOS.Core.dll.  It has a aospsdev.dll.

This is coming from parameters I am passing in to the MSBuild command:

```
/t:publish /p:InstallUrl=$(AppUpdateLocation) /p:UpdateUrl=$(AppUpdateLocation) /p:ApplicationVersion=$(REVISION_NUMBER) /p:ProductName=AOS-ProdSupport-Dev;AssemblyName=$(DEV_ASSEMBLY_NAME)
```

The assembly name I want to specify is only for the WinForms application (the AOS.Application project) - not everything else.

How do I go about specifying the assembly name for one project only so this solution can build?

Comment: Looks like this is my answer. [Msbuild command line argument at project-level not solution-level for changing AssemblyName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553524/msbuild-command-line-argument-at-project-level-not-solution-level-for-changing-a/15592458)

Comment: You should definitely not (not in a million years) be changing assembly names based on the build environment. That should be constant and unchanging. You can or should create different output folders based on your environment.

Comment: @CJohnson it was not an ideal scenario.  The problem is twofold:  1. it is a clickonce application - meaning it only installs under a users local account and 2.  I need to be able to run multiple instances of the application on the users machine due to concurrent development.  The only way that I know of to have simultaneous instances of an application on a users machine is to have different assembly names.  It also differentiates the instances on the users start menu.  Unless you know of a different way to do this - I would say this is 1 in a million years.